# MSSQL on Ubuntu, can't get it to install?

Tags: server, apt, mssql

Recently MS launched mssql-server for Linux. I'd like to use it but I can't manange to run

```
sudo apt-get install -y mssql-server
```

It says

```
E: Unable to locate package mssql-server
```

Current Ubuntu is 16.04.1 LTS.

I tried to follow [these instructions on Microsoft's website](
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-ubuntu) and don't know what else to do with it.

Comment: why would there be an mssql package in your 16.04 install? that package is not from Canonical. You need to do the `curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-server.list` and update.

Comment: i did follow and do this like i mentioned on my post. After looking inside its list, the arch is for amd64, im running 32 bit(i386), would that be a problem?

Comment: yes, you will need a 64 bit system. Doubt MS wants to support 32 bit ;)

Comment: lol and  here i was trying to run a experiment with pentium 4... oh wellll   guess its time to trash thissss :P

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install MSSQL Server and/or tools for Linux on 16.04?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/850957/how-do-i-install-mssql-server-and-or-tools-for-linux-on-16-04)

Comment: true but this was the first topic about the issue :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You will need a 64-bit system for this to work ;)

First, add the Xenial MSSQL repository to your system:

```
$ sudo curl -o /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-server.list https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server-2017.list
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    91  100    91    0     0    195      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   195
$ curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   983  100   983    0     0   2337      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  2340
OK
```

Second, update APT's list of available packages:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/numix/ppa/ubuntu yakkety InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security InRelease [93,3 kB]   
Hit:3 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety InRelease                    
Hit:4 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates InRelease            
Hit:5 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-backports InRelease          
Get:6 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server xenial InRelease [2828 B]
Get:7 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server xenial/main amd64 Packages [940 B]
Fetched 97,1 kB in 0s (204 kB/s)  
Reading package lists... Done
```

Optionally, you can check that it's ready to install:

```
$ apt-cache search mssql-server
mssql-server - Microsoft SQL Server Relational Database Engine
mssql-server-agent - Microsoft SQL Server Agent
mssql-server-fts - Microsoft SQL Server Full Text Search.
mssql-server-ha - The mssql-server-ha package contains HA extensions for the Microsoft SQL Server Relational Database Engine.
mssql-server-is - SSIS on Linux
```

Then, just install with `sudo apt install mssql-server`.

Comment: Precisely, you'll need AMD64 system. It won't work on ARM architecture (at least not yet).

Comment: Link is broken I believe

Comment: I was getting Full-Text error on a docker container with the latest image from microsoft/mssql-server-linux, I logged into the container terminal and couldn't execute `apt-get install -y mssql-server-fts`, this answear was all I needed. Thanks!

Comment: I think this is the best package install post I have come across. `Check that it's ready to install` is my favorite part.

Comment: @userfuser, Well, that makes sense. Guess no Raspberry Pi for me.

Answer (score 3):

I seached and finally found a [working solution](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-install-ms-sql-on-ubuntu-server-18-04/):

> #### Installation
>
> The first thing to do is import the necessary repository key. From the terminal window, issue the following command:
>
> ```
> sudo wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -
> ```
>
> Next, add the repository with the command:
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository "$(wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server-preview.list)"
> ```
>
> Update the APT database with the command:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get update
> ```
>
> And, finally, install MS SQL with the command:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install mssql-server -y
> ```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, while this link may answer the question, it's better to include essential parts here.

Comment: Thank you. The first step adding the keys was what I was needing